# Behavior of starred section in beamer

Tags: beamer, sectioning, numbering, starred-version

In a LaTeX article, `\section*` behaves like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} \begin{document}
\section*{Not numbered} \thesection % --> 0
\section{Numbered} \thesection % --> 1
\end{document}
```

However, with beamer the following happens:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer} \begin{document}
\section*{Not numbered} \frame{\thesection}  % --> 1
\section{Numbered} \frame{\thesection} % --> 2
\end{document}
```

Why is this? Could I correct this behaviour?

Now, what I actually need is a command `\secnr` for beamer that will print nothing when in a starred section and the correct -viz. documentclass article- numbering in unstarred sections. So that would require:

1. Fixing the numbering misbehavious in beamer
2. An `if` to test "if current section is starred ..."

A solution to either (or both) of these problems would be very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**beamer** implements `\section*` in a different way. The actual section number is kept in the (TeX) counter `\beamer@tocsectionnumber`, which is not advanced when `\section*` is found.

A possible solution to your problems is

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newif\ifstarred
\def\secnr{}
\makeatletter
\pretocmd\beamer@@ssection{\gdef\secnr{}\global\starredtrue}{}{}
\patchcmd\beamer@section{by 1\relax}
  {by 1\relax\xdef\secnr{\the\beamer@tocsectionnumber}\global\starredfalse}{}{}
\makeatother
```

This defines `\secnr` as you want: in a `\section*` it expands to nothing, while in a `\section` it expands to the section's number. The `\ifstarred` conditional is true after a `\section*` and false after a `\section`.

Comment: Thank you! Those pretocmd and patchcmd macros are stunning.