# subsection numbering in headline with smoothbar theme

Tags: beamer, numbering, themes

With the smoothbar outer theme (used by Darmstadt), I like the subsection headline, but I want to print the section and subsection number before.

I've tried to modify the headline template by adding `\thesection.\thesubsection\` in the line with `\insertsubsectionhead`, but the numbers are also in titlepage or in the summary, which i don't want.

I've tried to use `\insertsubsectionheadnumber` too, but it doesn't work :(.

MWE :

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme{smoothbars}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
\pgfuseshading{beamer@barshade}%
\ifbeamer@sb@subsection%
\vskip-9.75ex%
\else%
\vskip-7ex%
\fi%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[ignorebg,ht=2.25ex,dp=3.75ex]{section in head/foot}
    \insertnavigation{\paperwidth}
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\ifbeamer@sb@subsection%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[ignorebg,ht=2.125ex,dp=1.125ex,%
    leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
    \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\thesection.\thesubsection\ \insertsubsectionhead
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\fi%
}%
\makeatother

\AtBeginSection[]{
\begin{frame}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame} 
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Summary}
\tableofcontents%[pausesections]
\end{frame}

\section{section 1}
\subsection{sub 1}
\frame{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't want a headline at all on the title page and summary? Then just use the plain option for those frames: `\begin{frame}[plain]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not totally sure I understood your question correctly, but do you just want to hide the `\thesection.\thesubsection\` on slides with empty subsection?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme{smoothbars}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
\pgfuseshading{beamer@barshade}%
\ifbeamer@sb@subsection%
\vskip-9.75ex%
\else%
\vskip-7ex%
\fi%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[ignorebg,ht=2.25ex,dp=3.75ex]{section in head/foot}
    \insertnavigation{\paperwidth}
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\ifbeamer@sb@subsection%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[ignorebg,ht=2.125ex,dp=1.125ex,%
    leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
    \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}
    \ifx\insertsubsection\empty\else%
    \ifdefempty{\subsecname}{\relax}{%
        \thesection.\thesubsection\ \insertsubsectionhead%
    }%
    \fi
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\fi%
}%
\makeatother

\AtBeginSection[]{
\begin{frame}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame} 
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Summary}
\tableofcontents%[pausesections]
\end{frame}

\section{section 1}
\subsection{sub 1}
\frame{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, Thank you ! I just corrected it to use `\the\beamer@tocsectionnumber` instead of `\thesection`, as said in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24406/behavior-of-starred-section-in-beamer because I had a starred section